# Laravel- How to check difference between two time stamps on Carbon based on timezone

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I want to find out the difference between 2 times for the different timezone. 
I can take 2 times strings that are stored in our database and run cron job based on set timezone and 2 times (`$timeFrom` & `$timeTo`).

```
$timezone = $timezone // like (UTC)
$timeFrom = $timeFrom // like 09:00:00
$timeTo = $timeTo // like 01:00:00

date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$currentTime = Carbon::now();
$timeFrom = Carbon::parse($timeFrom)->minute(0)->second(0);
$dateExplode = explode(':',$timeTo);
$checkDate = ltrim($dateExplode[0],'0');

if($checkDate > 0 && $checkDate < 12){
   $timeTo = Carbon::parse($timeTo)->minute(0)->second(0)->addDay();
} else {
   $timeTo = Carbon::parse($timeTo)->minute(0)->second(0);
}

$check = $currentTime->between($timeFrom,$timeTo); // result TRUE/FALSE
```

When I used `between` run cron users timezone. Any thing I missed?

Comment: Once go through **difference** section of this [link](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: @rahulsm thanks for the quick response. Can you please explain in brief how can i use `Difference` in my code ?